# bottle.run(app) returns 404 - Not Found

Tags: bottle

I'm trying to run this very simple script:

```
import bottle

app = bottle.Bottle()

@bottle.route('/test')
def test():
    return 'hi'

bottle.run(app=app)
```

When I run the script, the bottle server starts correctly:

```
Bottle v0.11.6 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

and HTTP requests reach the server:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2013 14:43:52] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 728
```

Anyway I get a 404 response.

If I comment the third line and start bottle with `bottle.run()` everything works fine:

```
import bottle

#app = bottle.Bottle()

@bottle.route('/test')
def test():
   return 'hi'

bottle.run()  # RUN BOTTLE WITHOUT APP ARGUMENT
```

The HTTP response:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2013 14:55:38] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

I can't figure out what is the problem with the first snippet. Can you help me?

Comment: I found the error. I changed @bottle.route('/test')
decorator with @app.route('/test').

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it after the delay? This will resolve your question better than adding "solved" to the title.

Comment: I've posted the solution. Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error. I changed `@bottle.route('/test')` decorator with `@app.route('/test')`.